# How does Android translating group names?

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my app I'm reading group names and ids from device database, and I want to create list of group names for adding permissions, which type of contacts may be send to my http server. Group names in databse by defauls are in english language, but during adding/editing contacts they are translated to the present device language. My app should be fully multilanguage. How can I translate this in my app? I'm reading groups by following content uri:

```
ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
```

from column:

```
ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the 4 standard groups are created in English by default:

```
My Contacts
Family
Friends
Coworkers
```

Other groups are not in English by default, they are titled as the user created them.

You can detect those standard groups in your app (by comparing the title to one of those 4 strings), and add translation to your strings.xml file for each language you wish to support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you sure that only 4 groups are default? My Lenovo K5 device has additional: "Starred in Android" and "VIP" groups which didn't create by me. If it is possible to gather all static groups, your solution is pretty good, but I feel that another devices may have something else.

Comment: The 4 groups i mentioned are called "System groups", and are created by default by your Google Contacts account, "Starred in Android" is created by Google's SyncAdapter on Android, I'm not sure about "VIP", but I have an app on many different types of devices, and haven't seen any device-created groups anywhere, so I'd go for those 5, and you can add "VIP" as well